# exclude nm-tray NetworkManger from lxqt-notificationd

Tags: lubuntu, notification

I'm running lubuntu 20.04 (is upgrade from 19.04-->19.10)
The most time my network connection is to an guest account from a neighbor. the signal is sometimes weak, and I lose the connection; then the notification daemon gives me a bubble. this is annoying when I look videos. I'll try to exclude both nm-tray and NetworkManger through

```
lxqt-config-notificationd
```

and in file

```
$HOME/.config/lxqt/notifications.conf
```

but I have no Idea how to make it right.

this is after I try it from gui fronted.

```
cat .config/lxqt/notifications.conf 
[General]
__userfile__=true
blackList=nm-tray, "  NetworkManager"
server_decides=5
spacing=6
unattendedMaxNum=10
width=300
```

It looks for me wrong.

Note: After upgrade to lubuntu 20.04. I changed my config to

```
cat .config/lxqt/notifications.conf 
[General]
__userfile__=true
blackList=nm-tray, NetworkManager
placement=top-right
server_decides=5
spacing=6
unattendedMaxNum=10
width=300
```

Comment: Oh, I oversleept  it.

Comment: do-release-upgrade is running, now.

Comment: @guiverc done :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110766/discussion-between-nobody-and-guiverc).

Comment: Sorry my use of Ubuntu SSO means I cannot access SE services like chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, it is working. With my new config.

```
cat .config/lxqt/notifications.conf 
[General]
__userfile__=true
blackList=nm-tray, NetworkManager
placement=top-right
server_decides=5
spacing=6
unattendedMaxNum=10
width=300
```

great half answer.

Right click on nm-tray and remove notification. Now both are stopping spamming me.